# Python 2.7 is missing gzip.py in Yocto/OpenEmbedded Build

Tags: python, python-2.7, gzip, yocto, openembedded

In my native installation of python 2.7 on my PC on any distribution that I've looked at (i.e. Ubuntu) `gzip.py` is installed as part of the package. In fact, in the python 2.7 source itself, `gzip.py` is available.

However, when I build python 2.7 provided by the openembedded-core layer using commit `a9db40da62c13b0010ce5afc1fde16d987bdfbc6`, `gzip.py` is missing.

I've looked at the source code archive that is used to build python and (as expected) `gzip.py` is available in there. Furthermore I'm unable to find anything in the bitbake recipes which may trigger a python build without `gzip.py`.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a reason we are not seeing gzip.py in the yocto build?
2. Is there a way to get gzip.py installed as part of standard python using bitbake?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are missing the `gzip.py` in your build is probably that it is included in a separate package called `python-compression`.

This is caused by the `FILES_${PN}-compression=` statement in `python-2.7-manifest.inc`, see: https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/a9db40da62c13b0010ce5afc1fde16d987bdfbc6/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python-2.7-manifest.inc#L42

So including `python-compression` in your build should fix your problem.

Comment: Following up on this, if you want the entire Python library installed then install "python-modules".  In recent releases you can install 'python' to get all of the library, but older releases needed you to install python-modules.